# Customer Billing address should match on the credit card

Tags: magento-1.7, payment, paypal, payment-methods

I am using Paypal Payment Pro payment method and I want to restrict to customers to make sure that the billing address has to match the billing address on the credit card they are using.
Is this possible?
If yes, please let me know required configuration.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If this works like any other payment gateway, you have an account with Paypal Payment Pro that you can log into and set up various fraud check filters.

The one you're looking for is AVS (Address Verification Service) and it will allow for several different match checks, one being that both the address and postal code must match to accept the card.

The checks occur **at the processor** when you submit the card and the card acceptance or denial information is then sent back to Magento.